# How to update and generate DocBlock for the entire project in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have set up code inspection for php doc blocks, so now I will get warning if they are missing or incomplete.

[image: Code inspection for PHPDoc]

When I have one class open, I can use `Code > Generate > PhpDocBlocks` to generate them or just start a comment via `/*` in front of a method and it will be added.

Also, if exsiting doc blocks are incomplete or wrong, I can use `Update DocBlock` in order to match the DocBlock of a method to the actual method's signature.

Is there a way of applying these, both the doc block generation and, if necessary, the update of a doc block over the entire codebase without manually initializing this in each class?

I am looking for a batch process.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the project overview, you can right click a folder and select `Inspect Code`. It's also available via `Code > Inspect Code`.

A window will pop up asking you for further detail and you also can expect the scope to whole context.

Make sure your Inspection Profile contains PHPDoc. If the inspection has run through, you then will have a PHPDoc section,

[image: Result of Code Inspection]

By right clicking you then can `Apply Fix` even for multiple classes.

Answer (score 9):

Check this screenshot: [image]

You can read more about creating docs [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/creating-php-documentation-comments.html)

Comment: This only generates the docblock in the current class. The question is about all classes in the entire project.